# Finding statistical significance difference using Z score test using r

Tags: r, statistical-significance, z-test, ggplot2

I wonder how to perform the z proportion test to check which COG category of Shewanella_sp_Alg231_23 is significantly high p (<0.05) from other genomes. To undersatnd I have attached a bar braph.

```
    COG<-c("C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V")


Shewanella_sp_OPT2<-c(171,33,246,75,109,131,104,192,188,156,185,139,151,133,61,352,282,162,133,74)

Shewanella_spongiae_KCTC_22492<-c(154,43,221,72,95,125,94,184,184,205,168,105,133,107,47,316,269,151,146,70)

Shewanella_sp_Alg231_23<-c(294,36,331,81,149,183,125,209,328,168,245,136,197,204,91,444,395,337,134,75)


df<-data.frame(COG, Shewanella_sp_OPT2, Shewanella_spongiae_KCTC_22492,Shewanella_sp_Alg231_23)
```

and for plotting here, the code I used

```
library(reshape2)
df_long<-melt(df, id.vars="COG", value.name = "Number of proteins",
               variable.name = "Species")
```

Barplot

```
ggplot(dat_anoopl, aes(x = `COG`, y = `Number of proteins`, fill = Species)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", 
           stat ="identity", 
           width = 0.7)
```

But I would like to do the test statistics Z proportion test for my data and check which category is a significant difference, and if there is a difference, then how to show the way it is shown in the figure attached her, kindly help,

Comment: Please stop reposting the same question!  Visit our [help] to learn how this site works.  We encourage you to *edit* the original question in response to comments and suggestions.  It presently appears that you are asking for programming help, which is not on topic here.  If you have a statistical question, please edit *this* post to point out what it is.

Comment: An undocumented list of code can be difficult to interpret as a statistical question. Specifically, what differences do you want know are different?

Comment: As a part of my work, I have to find significant enriched COG class, I took this data from already published,  where Shewanella_sp_Alg231_23 has been compared with other data like Shewanella_spongiae_KCTC_22492, Shewanella_sp_OPT2 and found some of the cog class is significantly rich using test statistics z proportion test, I am trying to do the same but I couldnt do it. kindly help @BruceET

Comment: @whuber, no programming help, I am new to it and just through image I would like to state my purpose of doing z prortion test, so it can help me to get assist and I can understand If my purpose is served, old post is deleted as it got closed,

Comment: Please start by showing what worked. Then show how the same method doesn't work for other data, and exactly why you need help. // Usually, z test means pop SD is known. What is pop SD?

Comment: @BruceET, this data I took from one of published paper, u can find here "https://doi.org/10.3389/fmicb.2019.00005", kindly see the paper and let me know if require how I can do it

Comment: @BruceET, I will use 
`scores<-apply(df, 1,  zscore)`
but my next question is I want to find p valye from these z-score, so which hypothesis will be perfect one tail or two tail to reject null hypothesis at p value (0.05)